# Simple C++ code returns different outputs on different compilers

Tags: c++, string, pointers, memory, compiler-errors

I wrote a program in C++ that receives 2 strings as input and checks if one is the inverse of the other.

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<string>
  
  int main() {
    std::string word, word_inv;
    std::cin >> word; 
    std::cin >> word_inv;
    
    int n=word.size(), i=0;
    while(word_inv[i] == word[n-i-1])
      i++;
      
    std::cout << ((i == n) ? "YES" : "NO") << std::endl;
  }
```

However it gives different results on different compilers. For the input tests: `code`+`edoc` it prints `"YES"` on my computer but `"NO"` in the other.

I ran `g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o bin/program src/prog.cpp -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -g` and this is the output:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3341:30: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x00016ce73760 overflowed to 0x00016ce7375f
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3341:30 in 
=================================================================
==7114==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-underflow on address 0x00016ce7375f at pc 0x000102f8d750 bp 0x00016ce73730 sp 0x00016ce73728
READ of size 1 at 0x00016ce7375f thread T0
    #0 0x102f8d74c in main 41A.cpp:12
    #1 0x188a8542c in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64e+0x1842c)

Address 0x00016ce7375f is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 31 in frame
    #0 0x102f8d428 in main 41A.cpp:6

  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 56) 'word' (line 7) <== Memory access at offset 31 underflows this variable
    [96, 120) 'word_inv' (line 7)
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-underflow 41A.cpp:12 in main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x00702d9ee690: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee6a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee6b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee6c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee6d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x00702d9ee6e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1[f1]00 00 00 f2
  0x00702d9ee6f0: f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee700: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee710: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee720: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00702d9ee730: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==7114==ABORTING
```

Comment: That groovy scrawl is telling you that on like 12 the program was caught doing something awesomely stupid and was slapped down. 12 doesn't really line up all that well, so I'm going to take a better look at it.

Comment: @user4581301 on line 12 is the while loop, which is comparing the characters o inverse order. It is not giving me null pointer or out of range (at least it runs normally giving the correct result when I do not call the debug flags).

Comment: Sanitizers were less help in this case than looking at the the program running in the debugger.

Comment: @checkd *It is not giving me null pointer or out of range* -- Now it will, watch this: -- `while(word_inv[i] == word[n-i-1])` Change that to: `while(word_inv.at(i) == word.at(n-i-1))`.  What runtime error do you get?  Read it carefully, because it will explain everything to you.  Also, every standard C++ will give you this runtime error, so getting different output will be a moot point.

Comment: You could do this with a one-liner: `std::equal(word.begin(), word.end(), word_inv.rbegin())`.

Comment: @PeteBecker No. What if `word_inv.size() < word.size()` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo — sigh. Check the length. Or use the four-argument version. Either way, it’s much cleaner than managing the accesses explicitly.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm sure _you_ do that but implying that _generic algorithm_ replaces another to someone struggling with the basics may be counter productive. The code in the question has boundary problems. Your replacement (without explanations) has boundary problems - although the algorithm itself is neat.

Comment: @TedLyngmo — thank you for your input. I’ll give it the consideration it deserves.

Comment: @PeteBecker Happy to help. I don't mind if you quote me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(word_inv[i] == word[n-i-1])
```

This condition requires `word_inv[i]` to not be equal to `word[n-i-1]` for the loop to end. What if that doesn't happen while the indices are within bounds?

What happens then is that the program tries to read memory *out of bounds* with [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) as a result, which means that anything could happen. It could look like it's working while compiling with one compiler but not another. The apparent look that it's working could also stop the next day even if you use the same compiler as the day before.

You need to make sure that `i` and `n-i-1` are within bounds. If they are not, exit the loop.

---

Something that might help while developing these things is to use the bounds checking accessors. Many standard classes that provides `operator[]`, like `std::string`, also provide the member function `at`. Using that in your program would look like this:

```
while (word_inv.at(i) == word.at(n - i - 1)) i++;
```

This will throw an exception (independent of which compiler you use) and the exception message for `at` is often very informative.

Answer (score 1):

When do you stop checking characters in each word?

If you have CODE and EDOC, then you check char 0 against char 3, then 1 v 2, then 2 v 1, then 3 v 0, then 4 v -1... oops, you've overflowed your strings. I assume you run it in release build that has no bounds checking on tyhe computer where it works and you are accidentally seeing garbage being compared to different garbage that stops the check.